# Multer doesn't see uploaded image

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, multer

I want to save one image in single post request, which will be users's avatar to MongoDB, and also some users's information using package from npm called multer. Unfortunately only what I can see in console is error:
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'path' of undefined`

***register.pug***

```
extends layout
block content
   h1 Register
   form(method='POST', action='/users/register')
    .form-group
      label Username:
      input.form-control(name='firstName', type='text')
    .form-group
      label Email:
      input.form-control(name='lastName', type='text')
    .form-group
      label Name:
      input.form-control(name='email', type='text')
    .form-group
      label Password:
      input.form-control(name='password', type='password')
    .form-group
      label Avatar:
      input.file(name='avatar', id='avatar' type='file')
    input.btn.btn-primary(type='submit',value='Submit')
```

***register route***

```
const upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/avatars/' })
router.post('/register', upload.single('avatar'), (req, res, next) =>{
  const firstName = req.body.name;
  const lastName = req.body.name;
  const email = req.body.name;
  const password = req.body.name;
  let avatar = {
    path: req.file.path,
    orginalname: req.file.orginalname
  };

 let newUser = new User ({
   firstName: firstName,
   lastName: lastName,
   email: email,
   password: password,
   avatar: avatar
 });
}

newUser.save();
});
```

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uh, it took a while but i have found the reason, you need to give your files an ***extension***. I will put here my code

This is my **html** file, I am using `ejs` modules in my app instead of `jade`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form accept="image/x-png,image/gif,image/jpeg" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/profile" method="post">
      <input type="file" name="avatar" value="">
      <input type="submit" name="" value="ssss">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is my `app.js`, if the destination path in `cb` function doesn't exist, it creates the directory for you.

Then here comes the filename, you need to give it an extension, it could be `.png` like i did, or you could do `.jpeg`, however you like, but it must be an ***image extension***. Or you could just give it the ***extension*** that your client gives *you*.

Then we have our `upload` variable, which just sets up the pre-required functions for us.

```
var express = require('express')
var multer  = require('multer')
var app = express()

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, __dirname + '/uploads')      //you tell where to upload the files,
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + '.png')
  }
})

var upload = multer({storage: storage,
    onFileUploadStart: function (file) {
      console.log(file.originalname + ' is starting ...')
    },
});

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.get('/', function(req, res, next){    
    res.render('mult');  //our html document
})

app.post('/profile', upload.single('avatar'), function (req, res, next) {
  // req.file is the `avatar` file
  console.log(req.file);
  return false;
})
```

Comment: can you set it answered? @robmax

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are missing this attribute

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

in your form, give it a try !